# xamarin forms - listview - picker - wont align with rows in listview

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, grid

I have a listview inside a stacklayout...everything appears find on screen... apart from the picker which is about a cm out from the rest of the row...i have tried changing the height of the rows but to no avail...does anyone know why the picker... '0' isnt on the same horizontal alignment as the rest of the rows such as brandName, size and Price.

```
<Grid>
          
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
               
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0"> 
                <ListView x:Name="WineLV" IsVisible="True" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding WineL}" HeightRequest="50">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Transparent" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Padding="5">

                                <Frame OutlineColor="Black" Padding="10" BackgroundColor="Transparent">

                                    
                                    <Grid>

                                            
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="40"/> 
                                            
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="16*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="35*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="15*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="15*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="19*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>  

                                       

                                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Id}" VerticalOptions="End" IsVisible="False"/>
                                        <controls:CircleImage  Grid.Column="0"  Grid.Row="0" HeightRequest="60" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" Aspect="AspectFill" WidthRequest="66" Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="{Binding Img}"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding BrandName}" VerticalOptions="Start" FontSize="Medium"/>
                                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Grapes}" VerticalOptions="Start" FontSize="Medium"/>
                                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"  Text="{Binding Sizes}" VerticalOptions="Start" FontSize="Medium"/>
                                            <Picker Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Title="   0" x:Name="pPicker" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"  ItemsSource="{Binding ListQ}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Value}" SelectedIndexChanged="QuantityC" SelectedItem ="{Binding Selected}"/>
                                            <Label Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat='£{0:0.00}'}" FontSize="Medium"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                </Frame>
        </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            
        </StackLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: all the others have `VerticalOptions="Start"` - try changing them to Center, and possibly setting `VerticalTextAlignment` also

Comment: Thats great Jason thanks for the reply. That has resolved the issue. If you write up the A, ill mark it correct. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all the others have `VerticalOptions="Start"` - try changing them to `Center`, and possibly setting `VerticalTextAlignment` also